# How to use sample_by="document" argument with load_dataset in Huggingface Dataset?

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, huggingface, huggingface-datasets

### Problem

Hello. I am trying to use huggingface to do some malware classification. I have a 5738 malware binaries in a directory. The paths to these malware binaries are stored in a list called `files`. I am trying to load these binaries into a huggingface datasets.Dataset object.

I have created the Dataset like this

```
dataset = datasets.Dataset.from_text(
    files,
    sample_by="document",
    encoding="latin1",
)
```

Since each file is supposed to represent a single instance, I used `sample_by="document"`, which to my knowledge (confirmed by reading the source code) should treat each document in `files` as an individual example.

Strangely, the length of `files` and the length of the resulting `dataset` do not appear to be the same

```
dataset.num_rows, len(files)
>>> (27967, 5738)
```

The expected behavior was that each file in `files` would get mapped to a particular row in `dataset`, but apparently this did not happen. Any idea whats up with this? Thanks!

### Software

- datasets 2.12.0
- Python 3.10.6
- CentOS 9

### References

- [datasets.Dataset](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/package_reference/main_classes#datasets.Dataset)
- [datasets.packaged_modules.text.TextConfig](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/package_reference/loading_methods#datasets.packaged_modules.text.TextConfig)

Comment: What is in your files? Are you sure that the files contain one instance each?

Comment: @Junuxx `files` is a list of str files. Each file is supposed to be treated as a single instance, which I thought was the behavior of sample_by="document".

Answer (score 1):

Using these files as example from https://github.com/jstrosch/malware-samples/blob/master/binaries/nanocore/2020/March/samples_pcap_artifacts.zip

```
! wget https://github.com/jstrosch/malware-samples/raw/master/binaries/nanocore/2020/March/samples_pcap_artifacts.zip 
! unzip -P infected samples_pcap_artifacts.zip
```

```
$ ls
1ef872652a143f17864063628cd4941d.bin  NanoCoreBase.bin*
ClientPlugin.bin*                     NanoCoreStressTester.bin*
CoreClientPlugin.bin*                 NetworkClientPlugin.bin*
FileBrowserClient.bin*                SecurityClientPlugin.bin*
ManagementClientPlugin.bin*           SurveillanceClientPlugin.bin*
MyClientPlugin2.bin*                  SurveillanceExClientPlugin.bin*
MyClientPluginNew.bin*                ToolsClientPlugin.bin*
```

## Doing it the hard-way

Then to read them into bytes and huggingface Dataset:

```
from io import BytesIO
import glob

import pandas as pd
from datasets import Dataset

filenames = glob.glob('./*.bin')

filebytes = []
for fn in filenames:
  with open(fn, 'rb') as fin:
    filebytes.append(fin.read())

ds = Dataset.from_dict({'filename': filenames, 'content': filebytes})
```

## Using `load_dataset`

```
import glob

from datasets import load_dataset,Features,Value
from datasets import load_dataset

filenames = glob.glob('./*.bin')


ds2 = load_dataset("text", 
    data_files={"train": filenames}, 
    sample_by="document", 
    features=Features({'text': Value(dtype='string', id=None)}),
    encoding='latin-1'
)

ds2['train']
```

[out]:

```
Dataset({
    features: ['text'],
    num_rows: 14
})
```

Comment: Thank you I created a similar work-around constructing the dataset in a different manner. However, if you have any insight about the strange behavior above, I would be very curious to understand what is wrong about my interpretation of the documentation or if some kind of bug might exist in the API.

Comment: Use the `feautres=...` argument and see if it works for your files.